# Using PHP to dynamically generate a select tag from MySQL entry

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I have a simple equipment tracking form and in my edit table page I fill in the existing text values using `value="<?php echo $svc_tag;` for example. I have recently added a select tag but am stuck on how I can have the select box have the current value I am retrieving from MySQL chosen in the select box. Thru research I see the value attribute is not applicable here. Does anyone know of a way for me to have the select box populated with the current value from MySQL. I'm thinking along the lines I need some PHP code to generate the select code on the fly. This is what I have but it is not returning the value stored in MySQL;

```
Equipment Status:
    <?php   
    $option_to_preselect = $rsn_brwd;
    echo $option_to_preselect;
    $options = array
    (
        1 => 'Borrowed',
        2 => 'In for Repair',
        3 => 'Replacement',
        4 => 'Returned',
        5 => 'Other'
    );

    print '<select name="Borrwd_Rsn_val" id="input_select">';

    foreach ($options as $index => $value)
    {
        print '    <option value="' . $index . '"';

        if ($index == $option_to_preselect)
        {
            print ' selected ';
        }

        print '>' . $value . '</option>
    ';
    }

    print '</select>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update and post that this is how I solved the problem:

```
Equipment Status:

<?php    
$option_to_preselect = $rsn_brwd;

$ddown_options = array
(
    'Borrowed',
    'In for Repair',
    'Replacement',
    'Returned',
    'Other'
);

$arrlength=count($ddown_options);

print '<select name="ud_Borrwd_Rsn" id="input_select">';

for ($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{

    if ($ddown_options[$x] == $option_to_preselect)
    {
        print '    <option value="' . $ddown_options[$x] . '"' . ' selected="selected">' . $ddown_options[$x] . '</option>';

    }

    else {
            print '    <option value="' . $ddown_options[$x] . '">' . $ddown_options[$x] . '</option>';

          }

}
print '</select>';
?>
```